# TypeScript error for Parameter properties in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Using WebStorm

> WebStorm 2016.2.4
>   Build #WS-162.2228.20, built on October 18, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 x86
>   JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

WebStorm shows errors for the following Parameter properties:

```
export class Container2 {
    private readonly selector: string;

    constructor(readonly ele: ElementFinder,readonly name: string) {
        this.selector = extractSelectorFromLocator(ele.locator());
    }
}
```

The error is right after {{readonly}} and the error reads

> , or ) expected

FYI - my gulp TypeScript compiler shows no error and the code works fine at runtime (additional functions excluded from the example).

Additional Info:

TypeScript Compiler set to Custom - pointing to `node_modules/typescript/lib` which is used by the gulp tasks.

Has anyone encountered this issue or has a workaround?

Comment: the problem was fixed in WS2016.3 EAP

Comment: Good that is fixed in EAP that means we just have to wait until 2016.3 becomes stable until then TypeScript in moderation. Will give EAP a try anyway.